# How to access a spreadsheet in local file system using a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, sheetjs

I want to create a chrome extension that create a spreadsheet once installed on the browser and then get the path of this spreadsheet file and be ready to update that spreadsheet according to user interactions, i am using **sheet.js** to create and handle the spreadsheet

```
//the message is sent from background.js once the extension is installed
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( () => {
 if(message.action  ='createWorkbook') {
     try{
         //creating the workbook object sheet.js
         const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
         //hard coded spreadsheet header labels
         const worksheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(["name", "number", "age"]);
         var binaryString = XLSX.write(workbook, { type: "binary", bookType: "xlsx" });
         XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, "Sheet1");

         chrome.downloads.download({
             url: "data:application/octet-stream;base64," + btoa(binaryString),
             filename: "workbook.xlsx"
         })
     } catch () {}

 }
})
```

now this works and prompt the user to save the file to the local file system correctly, but i need also to get the path where the user saved the file so i can save it to the local storage and use it later to reach the spreadsheet location when the user interact with the extension so it can modify the spreadsheet using the data collected from the user interaction with the extension on a certain website.

I tried alot of things, i think **chrome.fileSystem** API is now deprecated, How can i achieve that?

Comment: I think that the file path can be obtained with `chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener`.